# Getting "IndexOutOfException" while adding list values to spinner

Tags: android

I'm adding list values in spinner but i getting the error is "`IndexOutOfException`" . How we place the spinner value in `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`
Anyone can help me please...

```
 if (categoryGLModel != null && categoryGLModel.getData().size() > 0) {
                spinnerDialog = new SpinnerDialog(getActivity(), list, "Select Category", R.style.DialogAnimations_SmileWindow, "Done", new AlertDoneClick() {
                    @Override
                    public void doneClick(int pos) {
                        Log.d("Login Fragment", "Done Click");
                     tvSpinnerTextView.setText(list.get(pos));
                    }
```

Comment: How did you create your list?

Comment: From ArrayList<String> List ; from arraylist object im getting list values (118 size) but once i click the item from list - app will be crashed.

Comment: Post the logcat please. And tell which exception lets your app crash.

Comment: is that SpinnerDialog class your own class?
Sorry for so many question but i don't wanna give random answer without be sure of if i get the problem.

Comment: Make sure that the index value sent in the variable pos exists in the list. If the list has 118 of size and pos value is < 0 or >= 118 the app will crash

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
       Fragments.UnassignedCategoryFragment$1.doneClick(UnassignedCategoryFragment.java:217)
        at in.galaxyofandroid.spinerdialog.SpinnerDialog$4.onClick(SpinnerDialog.java:182)

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira yes you correct the position is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Has you have said in the comments, the error happens when `pos = -1`.

`ArrayList` index starts from 0 and it works this way:

- Index 0: First element
- Index 1: Second element
- (...)

When you have pos as -1, it will reproduce this case:

```
tvSpinnerTextView.setText(list.get(-1));
```

This causes the `IndexOutOfException` because there is no index -1. Its importante for you to try to understand from where this -1 value comes.

If you want to avoid the crash, ignore the actions inside the event if the pos variable is less than 0:

```
if (categoryGLModel != null && categoryGLModel.getData().size() > 0) {
                spinnerDialog = new SpinnerDialog(getActivity(), list, "Select Category", R.style.DialogAnimations_SmileWindow, "Done", new AlertDoneClick() {
                    @Override
                    public void doneClick(int pos) {
                        if(pos > 0){
                           Log.d("Login Fragment", "Done Click");
                           tvSpinnerTextView.setText(list.get(pos));
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                            String categoryname = list.get(i);
                            tvSpinnerTextView.setText(categoryname);           // I modified code like this , now there is no crash for me ..Whether its correct or not ??

Comment: You dont want to set the text just when the user click in the spinner? This for doesn't do the same as your previous code.